# How do I start a JNLP application programmatically?

Tags: java, testing, integration-testing, jnlp

I have a working JNLP application, but would like to add some end-to-end smoke test.

Is it possible given an URL to download, start and programatically manipulate a JNLP application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start an JNLP application programatically(Linux) you could do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String[] cmd = {"/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_17_limpo/jre/javaws/javaws", "/opt/exata/projetosNB/InterfaceVisualizador/dist/launch.jnlp"};
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [javaws tool](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javaws/developersguide/javaws.html) (part of the JDK) to start a WebStart app. To programmatically manipulate it, you can use any of a number of testing tools and frameworks that simulate user input.